# Differences between @Transactional in Spring and @Transactional in JPA

Tags: java, spring, jpa, transactions

In my projects, someone uses @Transactional of JPA in their DAO classes, someone else uses @Transactional of Spring in their Service classes. It makes me confused a lot. Can you explain to me the differences between them? The pros and cons of each way?

Thanks a lot.